# Add Subviews to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have to put some labels into a UITableViewCell but there are different number of labels in each row. I'm trying to add a subview in each cell but when I do scroll all the labels overlap .

I have a for with the number of labels I want with this code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"dayCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];    

UILabel* titleLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
NSString * stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[[days objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8, 2)], [self getNameDay:[arrayOfWeek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
titleLabel.text = stringDate;
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

if ([keys containsObject:[days objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:15.0];
    [cell.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];

    NSDictionary * eventConcret = [events objectForKey:[days objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSArray * keysEventConcret = [eventConcret allKeys];
    CGRect frame = titleLabel.frame;

    for (int i=0; i<[keysEventConcret count]; i++) {

        for (int j=0; j<[[eventConcret objectForKey:[keysEventConcret objectAtIndex:i]] count]; j++) {

            frame.origin.y += 35;
            UILabel *hourEvent = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            hourEvent.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat: [self getHourStringFromDate:[[[eventConcret objectForKey:[keysEventConcret objectAtIndex:i]] objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"event_start"]]];
            hourEvent.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            hourEvent.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:15];
            hourEvent.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0/255.0 green:102.0/255.0 blue:102.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            hourEvent.tag = 3;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:hourEvent];

            frame.origin.y += 25;
            UILabel *contentEvent = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            contentEvent.text = [[[eventConcret objectForKey:[keysEventConcret objectAtIndex:i]] objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"event_title"];
            [contentEvent setNumberOfLines:0];
            contentEvent.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            contentEvent.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Regular" size:15];
            contentEvent.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:89.0/255.0 green:187.0/255.0 blue:98.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            contentEvent.tag = 4;

            [cell addSubview:contentEvent];

            UIButton *buttonContent = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            buttonContent.frame = frame;
            buttonContent.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            buttonContent.titleLabel.text = [keysEventConcret objectAtIndex:i];
            buttonContent.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            buttonContent.tag = indexPath.row+j*1000;
            [buttonContent addTarget:self
                              action:@selector(chooseEventButton:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:buttonContent];

        }

    }

}
else{
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Light" size:15.0];

    }

return cell;
```

}

The result is this image:
[image]
What's the way to do it correctly? Where I have to make the addSubview?

Thanks!

Comment: show the entire code of cellForRowAtIndexPath, your problem is that your cell is reusable

Comment: Use storyboard. You can do easily in storyboard with add UITableViewCell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this problem appears only after you scroll more than one TableView height!?
The problem is that cells are reused. So when you add new labels to a reused cell the old ones are still there. You need to remove all subviews from contentView before adding the new ones.
If you have a custom UITableViewCell class you can do so in prepareForReuse() method.

Comment: Problem solved: I remove all subviews in every iteration! 
 
    NSArray* subviews = [cell.contentView subviews];
    for (UIView* subview in subviews) {
        if (subview.tag==100) {
            //res
        }
        else{
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }